# Assembler Code Analysis

Tags: assembly

I found a tutorial with this line:

```
push   $0x8048478
```

with the explanation that $0x8048478 is the same as "%d\n". My question is how to know for what code the hex-code stands. How can a convert such an hex-code in useful code?

Comment: Can you link to this tutorial?

Comment: It's probably just the *address* of the string literal  `"%d\n"`.

Comment: But how can I find out this, if I just have the hex-code? ... here is the [link](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2Fafs%2Fcs.cmu.edu%2Facademic%2Fclass%2F15213-f02%2Fwww%2FR03%2Fsection_b%2FR03-B.ppt&ei=B2q1UeGaDqbF7Aa3woHYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEo8K_sl6LJlKx3l7Evf9bMMh5BWg&sig2=pEdxGcBYu_xlzM-YfCmMQg&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bGE) it's on page 22.

Comment: I agree with Paul R - it's an address. And they're not showing you enough of the decompiled code for you to see how the data is defined at that address. If you take the C code shown at the end and pass it through your own compiler, using whatever options cause it to spit out the assembly, you'll have a clearer picture (although it may not use `$0x8048478`).